# Adding a click behavior to a non-anchor component without using the Link component

Tags: java, wicket

I have a `DataView`, whose html is something like this:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Username</td>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>         
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr wicket:id="dataView">
         <td wicket:id="username">Username</td>
         <td wicket:id="firstName">First Name</td>
         <td wicket:id="lastName">Last Name</td>         
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My goal is to make the entire row clickable. I would use a `Link` component, but I can't - each `<tr>` element in the `dataView` is already an `Item`. Is there an easy way to append the kind of behavior that `Link` gets when it is not attached to an `<a>` tag? I.e. the behavior where it generates the javascript to do the link functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1:**  Add an "onclick" `AjaxEventBehavior` to each item:

```
new DataView<T>(id, dataProvider) {

    @Override
    protected void populateItem(Item<T> item) {

        item.add(new AjaxEventBehavior("onclick") {

            @Override
            protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                // This will execute when row is clicked
            }

        });

        // Continue populating item here
    }
}
```

**Option 2:** If you don't want to use Ajax, you can make all cells in each row a link to the same thing, then use CSS to make the links take up the entire cell space.  See this [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/khru4/).

Comment: Note that adding a `onclick` to each table-cell generatas loads of Javascript code, which might slow down your page.

Comment: @angstadt530 Wouldn't using an ajax behavior cause a much bigger than necessary overhead for a standard link?

Comment: @RobAu Since the behavior would be added on each `Item`, it would only be generated for each row, rather than cell (which is okay-ish).

Comment: For better performace: you could add the `onclick` to the table, and write some custom JavaScript to get the parents of the clicked element until you reach a `TR`. This `TR` should have an `id` (setOutputMarkupId(true)). You can then pass this `id` as extra parameters to the behavior and in wicket find the matching `TR` in the component Tree. See also for example this: https://github.com/RobAu/wicket-jq-autocomplete/blob/master/jq-autocomplete/src/main/java/org/audenaerde/onchildeventbehavior/OnChildEventBehavior.java

Comment: @RobAu I'm not too worried about performance of javascript, as the table in question will never be large (under 10 elements in most cases). However, I am worried that an ajax call is much more expensive than a call to a simple standard `Link`. Is that a valid concern?

Comment: That mainly depends on what you do in your 'onclick' code. Using ajax has the advantage that it might trigger only a small render/redraw action, so that might actually be cheaper than rendering the entire page again via a non-ajax link. The bit of javascript that handles the click is so fast you will not notice the difference at all.

Comment: @RobAu the links take you to a different page, which is why I thought using a standard link would be preferable to using a non-ajax link (thinking it would probably be more efficient). I guess I'll use this, if there is no performance cost.
Regardles, thank you for your help.

Comment: @WiseTree I added a second option in case you want to try not using Ajax.  Just use `BookmarkablePageLink` instead of hard-coding the links in the HTML like my example shows.